# Почему возникает ошибка при использовании final-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

Использую final-form + react при выполнении кода возникает ошибка Error: No onSubmit function specified. Как исправить данную ошибку ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Field} from 'react-final-form';



function LoginForm() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Form 
                render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h2>Simple Default Input</h2>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" component="input" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>

        <h2>An Arbitrary Reusable Input Component</h2>
        <div>
          <label>Interests</label>
          <Field name="interests" component='input' />
        </div>

        <h2>Render Function</h2>
        <Field
          name="bio"
          render={({ input, meta }) => (
            <div>
              <label>Bio</label>
              <textarea {...input} />
              {meta.touched && meta.error && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
            </div>
          )}
        />

        <h2>Render Function as Children</h2>
        <Field name="phone">
          {({ input, meta }) => (
            <div>
              <label>Phone</label>
              <input type="text" {...input} placeholder="Phone" />
              {meta.touched && meta.error && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
            </div>
          )}
        </Field>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )}
        />
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, у вас не хватает onSubmit

```
 <Form
   onSubmit={onSubmit}
```